# How can I fix Unknown token: vault_auth_backend.approle.path

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

So there's this tutorial page on terraform about [vault_approle_auth_backend_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/resources/approle_auth_backend_role):

```
resource "vault_auth_backend" "approle" {
  type = "approle"
}

resource "vault_approle_auth_backend_role" "example" {
  backend        = vault_auth_backend.approle.path
  role_name      = "test-role"
  token_policies = ["default", "dev", "prod"]
}
```

But when I copy the sample code and try to run `terraform init` there's an error:

```
Unknown token: vault_auth_backend.approle.path
```

How can I fix it?

I noticed that `backend` parameter is optional, can I just skip it? I feel like I'd like to set its value to `$VAULT_ADDR/v1/identity/oidc/role` or something.

If I use `backend        = "${vault_auth_backend.approle.path}"`, it still shows `backend: "${vault_auth_backend.approle.path}"` when running `terraform plan`.

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using? That looks like an error you'd get on Terraform versions before 0.12. If so you should include the `terraform0.11` tag in your question and explain why you can't use a version released in the last 18 months.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR well, we use the old version on my current project.

Comment: Then you need to use old HCL1 syntax which is why you are seeing that error when trying to use HCL2 (Terraform 0.12+) syntax.

Comment: Sure, but when I use `"${vault_auth_backend.approle.path}"` it still shows `backend: "${vault_auth_backend.approle.path}"` when I run `tf plan`.

Comment: That's just that it's a computed output. When you run apply it will then return the computed output but it doesn't know what it's going to be at plan time.